# How would I total two sets of numbers entered by a user?

Tags: java, eclipse, sum

I am writing a program where I must ask the user how many assignments they have. Then, I must ask them for their score and the maximum points possible for the assignment. I know how to find the sum of the first set of numbers they entered (their scores) but I am stuck on how I would go about totaling the maximum points possible. Here is what I have so far:

```
      int totalNumber = scan.nextInt();
                double sum = 0.0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumber; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Assignment " + i + " score and max? ");
                    double score = scan.nextDouble();
                    double maxScore = scan.nextDouble();
                    sum += score;
```

The output looks something like this:
Assignment 1 score and max? 16   17
Assignment 2 score and max? 18   19

I am not sure how I would total the maximum points (17 and 19 in the example) because I must print the total points:
(sum of scores)/(sum of maximum points).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the simple answer is to add another variable for summing the maxScore

```
 int totalNumber = scan.nextInt();
 double sum = 0.0;
 double maxSum = 0.0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumber; i++) {
     System.out.print("Assignment " + i + " score and max? ");
     double score = scan.nextDouble();
     double maxScore = scan.nextDouble();
     sum += score;
     maxSum += maxScore;
 }
```